# splice js function is not working in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

[image: inputlist]

**JS controller**
OUTPUT
input of json
[input json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hr2bTnVUf--bsjbe1qYFHpVSPtQNaiPN/view?usp=sharing)
getting out not expected
[output json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hr2bTnVUf--bsjbe1qYFHpVSPtQNaiPN/view?usp=sharing)

```
    var lst = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(component.get('v.lstPetval')));
        var lstInsert = [];
        var lstdel = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(component.get('v.lstPetDeletedVal')));

        var lstPetUpdateVal = [];
        for(var i=0; i<lst.length; i++) {
            lstInsert.push(lst[i]);
            if(lst[i].objAddOns.hasOwnProperty('Id')) {
                //console.log('lst[i]', lst[i]);
                lstPetUpdateVal.push(lst[i]);

            }
            // if(lst[i].objAddOns.hasOwnProperty('Id')) {
            //  lstInsert.splice(i, 1);
            // }
        }
        console.log('lstInsert', lstInsert);
        for(var i=0; i<lst.length; i++) {
            // console.log('lst[i]123', lst[i]);
            // if(lst[i].objAddOns.hasOwnProperty('Id')) {
            //  console.log('lst[i]', lst[i]);
            //  console.log('lst[i]', lst.indexOf(lst[i]));             
                lstInsert.splice(i, 1);

            // }
            // if(lst[i].objAddOns.hasOwnProperty('Id')) {
            //  
            // }
        }

        if(lstInsert.length == 0){
            lstInsert = null;
        } 
        if(lstdel.length == 0){
            lstdel = null;
        }
        if(lstPetUpdateVal.length == 0){
            lstPetUpdateVal = null;
        }
        console.log('lstInsert',lstInsert,'lstdel',lstdel,'lstPetUpdateVal',lstPetUpdateVal);




[![Here is the screen shot of input and output of JSON][2]][2][![output][2]][2]
```

Comment: You have the posted the controller code and console output. what's the error you are facing?

Comment: i getting the error like split function split the value only three index. but my input list has six values

Answer (score 1):

The reason is splice has three parameters and first one is the index , second one is how many elements to remove and finally items to be added . In your case , you have given only two parameters and the system is removing (0,2,4 indexes from original array) Hence you are seeing only half the values.